# how to get discount information (discount amount net, discount amount gross and discount percentage) from orders made on shopware 6.5

Tags: php, symfony, repository, shopware

Hello I working with a shopware store project.

I have an order repository as below

```
 $order = $this->orderRepository

   

 ->search(new Criteria([$event->getOrderId()]), $event->getContext())



->first();
```

now  within my order repository I am trying to get the discount details after using a promo code as below in my Lin items

```
  $order = $event->getOrder();

$lineItems = $order->getLineItems();
```

I take payload as in :

```
 $payload = $details->getPayload();



$discountValueorGross = $payload['value'];

            $tax = $details->getPrice()->getCalculatedTaxes()->first();

            $taxValue = $tax->getPrice();

            $price = $details->getTotalPrice();

            $taxRate = $tax->getTaxRate();

            $discountAmountNet = $discountValueorGross - ($discountValueorGross * $taxRate);

            $discount_percentage = ($discountAmountNet / $details->getPrice()->getUnitPrice()) * 100;
```

all these works, but I am been told that the calculation is off, I really don't know what else to do.

**has anyone else been able to get a (discount amount net, discount amount gross and discount percentage) accurately**